# Umbraco package ails post deployment

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We have installed the KeyValueEditor in our project - https://bitbucket.org/rbdigital/umbraco-keyvalue-editor/

When we deploy to any other environment, the code that uses this plugin fails and we have to uninstall the package and re-install on the environment

The plugin is referenced in the `installedPackages.config` file and the `App_Plugins\KeyValueEditor` is included in the project in Visual Studio

Why is the deployment affecting the plugin?

Comment: How are you deploying? Through VS or through a separate build server/tool? Also, when you check the file system do you see the necessary files where they should be?

Comment: Thanks @MikeB - we deploy through a TFS build process. I checked the file system after the build and the `installedPackages.config` file looks fine and the plugin itself appears to be all in order in the `App_Plugins` folder

Comment: Probably a silly question, but I assume you've run the Release.bat file and are including all the necessary binaries as well? May be worth comparing your bin folders across local and your remote env.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like installing this plugin could be modifying some file/files that you are then overwriting with your build scripts. When you then reinstall the package after deploying, the modifications are made again and then the package works.

I would try doing a complete backup of the directory with the output of your build server (when the package is in a non-working state) - then install the package in your site and confirm it works. Then use a diff tool to compare all files between the directory with the site and the directory with the backup to see what is changed.

Hopefully you should see a difference between the two folders and then you can fix up your build scripts accordingly.